# amplify pin point Opted-in endpoints 0 for flutter app

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I have added push notifications with pin point and FCM. It works fine on test device.

I am seeing two end points but when I am creating a campaign the Opted-in endpoints **0** endpoints

Why is this zero , how can I send push notification to these endpoints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because, by default, AWS analytics has an "opt-out" flag for all endpoints. For JS, you can use the example [from their documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/analytics/getting-started/q/platform/js/#update-endpoint) to set the flag to NONE.

For Flutter I am yet to find any solutions. Momentarily, the [AWS Analytics Pinpoint](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_analytics_pinpoint) library does not support this function.

Comment: Firebase is only best solution for now